# Override the Devise redirect path, using params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have followed the guide [How To: Override confirmations so users can pick their own passwords as part of confirmation activation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation). I all works smooth.

My mailer ends up sending a confirmation link a la:

```
"https://example.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=foo"
```

After the user has chosen his new password ensures that the user is redirected to the standard `after_sign_in_path_for`:

```
def do_confirm
  @confirmable.confirm
  set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed
  sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, @confirmable)
end
```

But what if I want to redirect the user to an individual page, specifically tailored for this user? Like e.g.:

```
"https://example.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=foo&redirect_to=#{CGI.parse('custom_path')}"
```

How would I set this up?

Comment: By overriding the `after_sign_in_path_for` method with whatever logic you like, probably in the `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Note that there is a potential security concern to be aware of, however: If you blindly redirect to *any* `redirect_to` value, then a malicious user could send links like: `"https://example.com/users/sign_in&redirect_to=http://www.my-fake-copy-of-your-website.com/scam"`. So you need to perform a check along the lines of: `URI.parse(params[:redirect_to]).hostname == hostname`.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom says in the above comment, you want to override the [`after_sign_in_path_for`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for) method.

There is a page on [devise's GitHub wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in) that explains this in more detail and gives a code example (if you use OAuth it will look a little different):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  protected  
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      sign_in_url = new_user_session_url
      if request.referer == sign_in_url
        super
      else
        stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
      end
    end
end
```